# ASP.NET XML to JSON for httphandler

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-services, json

Can anybody recommend the best way to do this?

Should I use JSON.NET?

Comment: Are you using asmx or WCF services?

Comment: So, you're trying to convert xml from your web services to json via httphandler?  The reason I asked what type of web service is because asmx supports this by appending /js to the web service call and WCF supports this by adding an additional endpoint.  If you're just trying to serve xml files as json, you may want to look at Ajax.NET pro, which implements a JSON handler.  You may be able to tweak the code to fit your needs. http://ajaxpro.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx). It's a great JSON serialization/deserialization library with huge community support and one of the best options performance-wise ([even ASP.NET WebApi](http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/06/aspnet-mvc-4-rc/) is using it as its default serializer).

You can also use .NET [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) or [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) in case you can't or prefer not to reference an external library in your project for a simple task (if that's your case).